# Bind(A.class) in Google Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm newbie to this Google Guice DI .I was going through some online articles for Dependency Injection  , In Google Guice , we generally specify the binding in Module Class like following :

```
bind(A.class).toInstance(B.class);
```

That means if we're trying to instantiate A's object , it should use B's class to instantiate it.

But sometimes , we do

```
bind(A.class);
```

what does this simply A.class binding means , we're binding it with itself . What could be the possible use of this kind of binding .

Comment: Presumably `A` is instantiable (not an interface or abstract class), and Guice knows about all of its dependencies in the module.

Comment: So what does this mean when you say guice knows about all of its dependencies . If we're not binding it with anyOne , can we use it directly without having it in Module.java of Google-Guice ?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/UntargettedBindings):

> You may create bindings without specifying a target. This is most
> useful for concrete classes and types annotated by either
> @ImplementedBy or @ProvidedBy. An untargetted binding informs the
> injector about a type, so it may prepare dependencies eagerly.
> Untargetted bindings have no to clause, like so:
>
> ```
> bind(MyConcreteClass.class);
> bind(AnotherConcreteClass.class).in(Singleton.class);
> ```